# array_search returning wrong value

Tags: php

I'm implementing manually the `array_unique` function. I'm doing this:

```
class Prelude {
    public static function unique($xs) {
        $arr = array();
        foreach($xs as $atom) {
            if (!array_search($atom, $arr)) {
                var_dump($arr); 
                echo "<br>";
                array_push($arr, $atom);
            }
        }
        return $arr;
    }
}

Prelude :: unique(array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 6, 7, 8));
```

I noticed that it works very well, **except** when `$atom` is `1`. In my `foreach` loop, when I check if the value is already contained in the array and the value I want to check is one, it simply ignores and says me that there is no `1` in my array. Here is my output:

http://ideone.com/HpWtIl

And here is when I check if there is `1`  in `[1, 1, 1]`:

http://ideone.com/eF3gcS

Can somebody explain me this?

Comment: `array_search()` can return `0` which is loosely equivalent to false, you should be doing `if(array_search($atom, $arr) === false)` to check if it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, Marcelo.

You're checking with `!` which is the non-strict checking. You must check for !== FALSE.
1 is TRUE.

Comment: PHP type coercion sucks. :(

Comment: You have the third parameter of ```array_search``` which performs strict checking on the needle.